# Eventbrite get specific event details by Id

Tags: eventbrite

I'm tryng to fetch the event details on my event on eventbrite.
But i'm only getting a 404 page back ? The url are maybe not correct..

I'm trying with a ajax call to get some info for this.

EventID: 41993118548

```
url: 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/events/41993118548?
status=live&expand=venue',
```

Anyone that can see what's wrong with the url ?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that i needed the v3... hmm

https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/'+ id +'/?status=live&expand=venue,tickets,currency

Well it works now.